# Microsoft Office- I purchased it but it is telling me that my license has been used too many times

Tags: microsoft-office

I purchased a copy of Microsoft Office Student Edition last year. My computer's hard drive crashed which meant that I had to reinstall the software and use the serial code again. It is now telling me though that the number of uses has been exceeded.

Is there a way to tell Microsoft that I'm trying to validate on the same machine that I was already operating on? I really don't want to have to purchase it again to run on the same machine that it was already running on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to call the number provided by the message produced by Office. You definitely do not need to purchase it again. Simply call them and tell them what's going on. You should be good to go.

Comment: +1 Microsoft should be able to assist quickly. This happens often and it usually takes a 10-15 minute call (sometimes less than 5 minutes) to sort it out.

Comment: Yea, MS is usually pretty good with these things. Most of the time it's automated or you will speak to someone fairly quickly.

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: MS customer support is actually really good.